# How to synchronously check for TCP connectivity in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

The application needs to consistently check if any of multiple servers is available. I want this to be done in the background periodically and just check the status of the last check whenever I need to know connectivity status. Being able to use a socket synchronously like you can in other languages would be helpful so that my periodic async func isn't running a bunch of its own async function and because in my case, any of the servers being successful is good enough for a success status. The other ones shouldn't be checked anymore and the other ones shouldn't be setting the overall status as bad just because one of the async tasks was bad.

Current Async situation

```
function checkServersPeriodically() {
    var servers = [{'host': 'localhost', port: 80}, {'host': 'localhost', port: 95}];
    for (var i = 0; i < servers.length; i++) {
        someAyncFunction(servers[i].host, servers[i].port, (err) => {
             //could have two async checks with different outcomes
             if (err) bad();
             else good();
        });
    }
}
```

What I was looking for (similar to if I were to do use some sort of file system check I'd  just use fs.readSync)

```
 function checkServersPeriodically() {
    var servers = [{'host': 'localhost', port: 80}, {'host': 'localhost', port: 95}];
    for (var i = 0; i < servers.length; i++) {
        try {
            someSyncFunction(servers[i].host, servers[i].port);
            good();
            return; // Skips the other checks
        } 
     }
     bad();
 }
```

Comment: Why would it have to be synchronously?  That's going to be really difficult.  It would be better if you used a proper structure in your application.

Comment: No, just use the async functions. If you need specific help with this, show us what you have tried and explain what you need. Perhaps all you need is an `async await` call

Comment: if you need to check this periodically, you would use `setInterval`, so **you already do this asynchronously**

Comment: You cannot use asynchronous API synchronously. Because it's **a**synchronous. *so doing it synchrnously is easier* - doing this properly would make everything easier. You have XY problem, consider reasking the question with detailed explanation of your real problem with asynchronous calls.

Comment: @estus updated with explanation of what I'm trying to do and the problem I'm having with async call

Comment: As it was already suggested, this is a common use case for async..await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be conveniently handled with `async..await` which provides synchronous-like control flow for promises:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const somePromiseFunction = promisify(someAyncFunction);

async function checkServersPeriodically() {
    var servers = [{'host': 'localhost', port: 80}, {'host': 'localhost', port: 95}];
    for (var i = 0; i < servers.length; i++) {
        try {
            await somePromiseFunction(servers[i].host, servers[i].port);
            good();
            return; // Skips the other checks
        } catch (err) {}
     }
     bad();
 }
```

`checkServersPeriodically` returns a promise. There's a chance that callbacks like `good` and bad` are remnants of callback-based API, and a success or a failure should be handled in caller function instead:

```
async function checkServersPeriodically() {
    var servers = [{'host': 'localhost', port: 80}, {'host': 'localhost', port: 95}];
    for (var i = 0; i < servers.length; i++) {
        try {
            await somePromiseFunction(servers[i].host, servers[i].port);
            return; // Skips the other checks
        } catch (err) {}
     }
     throw new Error('no servers');
 }

checkServersPeriodically().then(good, bad);
```